# Resize the text and keep the color box the same size

Tags: fonts, fontsize, boxes

Hi I have a gray box that contains my python code, I want to reduce the size of the code, but keep the grey box the same size. This is my latex code:

```
\lstset
{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language={Python},
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{9}\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
    tabsize=4,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
}


\fcolorbox{gray}{gray!15}{
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{./Code/get_zip_files.py}
```

Without specifying the font size, the output looks like this:

[image]

With the code I mentioned at the top (including the font size) it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the box became smaller. Is there a way to keep the same size for the box but lower the font size at the same time?

Comment: Welcome.  It would be best to post a complete minimal document that we can run, cf. [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably best to set the frame up with the mechanisms that `listings` provides, e.g.

```
backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15},
rulecolor=\color{gray},
frame=tlrb
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset
{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language={Python},
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{9}\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{green},
    tabsize=4,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15},
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    frame=tlrb
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
A full line of text before the sample code.
A full line of text before the sample code.
A full line of text before the sample code.
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
import requests

path = 'A:/Thesis_project/SBP/'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!